# Bind dropdown value to paginations itemsPerPage Angular 4

Tags: angular, binding, dropdown

I've imported simple pagination on my page and want it to bind number of items per page to values of my dropdown list, how can I do that?

Here's some code

```
     <tr *ngFor="let a of animals | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 8, currentPage: 
  p}>
            <td>{{a.name}}</td>
            <td>{{a.color}}</td> 
     </tr>
```

And pagination controls

```
   <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event "></pagination-controls>
```

I've added simple dropdown and want to bind value of selected dropdown to itemsPerPage, how can I do that?

```
  <div class="col-md-offset-11">
        <select id="PerPage" class="form-control">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to persist the pageSize through a NgModel in your component and use it as a parameter of your filter :

So bind the select to a model, and use ngValue to get a real numeric value ( regular value would output a string )

```
<div class="col-md-offset-11">
    <select id="PerPage" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pageSize">
        <option [ngValue]="5">5</option>
        <option [ngValue]="10">10</option>
        <option [ngValue]="25">25</option>
    </select>
</div>

....
<tr *ngFor="let a of animals | paginate: {itemsPerPage: pageSize, currentPage: p}>
    <td>{{a.name}}</td>
    <td>{{a.color}}</td> 
</tr>

....

// in the component
...
private pageSize: number = 5;
...
```

Comment: thanks men, while waiting for the answer I've figured it out myself lol, something insecurity really hurts